# Angular bindings with classes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angularjs-directive

angular with es6 classes giving me trouble and I can't find documentation on using this anywhere.
I have this controller

```
class AController {
  conversation: any;

  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
  }

  $onInit() {
    console.log(this.conversation) // This is undefined.
  }
}
```

and I have this component

```
export const AComponent = function () {
  return {
    template: require('./attachments.component.jade'),
    bindings: {
      conversation: '<'
    },
    controller: AController,
    controllerAs: '$ctrl'
  };
}
```

and this in a tempalte. `conversation` exists here.

```
attachments(conversation='conversation')
```

The template and controller are working but `this.conversation` is undefined. Can't figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: the controller for that template is using $scope, so `$ctrl.conversation` won't work

Comment: That looks like TypeScript, not ES6?

Comment: You're right, sorry. Changed it.

Comment: For documentation on AngularJS with ES6 see, [*Todd Moto:* AngularJS styleguide (ES2015)](https://github.com/toddmotto/angularjs-styleguide#angularjs-styleguide-es2015)

Comment: Is the attribute value `'conversation'` you trying to pass is a string or variable from some controller scope? if you are trying to pass string, wrap it with quote or change the binding to `@` instead of `<`

Comment: It is not a string

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks right, it's just that `this.conversation` might not be defined by the time `$onInit` is invoked.

You can either check if `conversation` is defined in `$onChanges`, or use a higher level abstraction like [ngcomponent](https://github.com/coatue-oss/ngcomponent) and check if `this.props.conversation` is defined in its `render()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `$onChanges` life-cycle hook to see values from a one-way binding:

```
class AController {
  conversation: any;

  constructor() {
    'ngInject';
  }

  $onInit() {
    //console.log(this.conversation) // This is undefined.
  }

  $onChanges(changes) {
      if (changes.conversation) {
          console.log(changes.conversation.currentValue);
      }
  }
}
```

> #### Life-cycle hooks
>
> - `$onChanges(changesObj)` - Called whenever one-way (`<`) or interpolation (`@`) bindings are updated. The `changesObj` is a hash whose keys are the names of the bound properties that have changed, and the values are an object of the form `{ currentValue, previousValue, isFirstChange() }`. Use this hook to trigger updates within a component such as cloning the bound value to prevent accidental mutation of the outer value. Note that this will also be called when your bindings are initialized.
>
> [— AngularJS Comprehensive Directive API Reference (Life-Cycle Hooks)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)